# CORS and Ajax requests in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, soap, webview, android-webview

I'm using Ionic 3 to develop an app, but the problem is that all of the company's webservices is based in SOAP requests.

In the preview of the app, using `ionic serve --lab`, I tried to do ajax requests using `Http Module`, but every time that I do a request I get this error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/soapwebservice. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Tried to used `jQuery Ajax` and `XMLHttpRequest` directly in the console too, but still get the error.

#### -- Edit

Found that when using `ionic cordova run android --device` to test in the device, the problem goes away. In the device the origin don't exist, because the app is run on `file:///`, and in the `ionic serve` the origin is in `localhost`, so it shows the CORS error.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific issue you having. Please take a minute to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to make it.

When using `ionic cordova run android --device` to test in the device, the problem goes away. In the device the origin don't exist, because the app is run on `file:///`, and in the `ionic serve` the origin is in `localhost`, so it shows the CORS error.

To fix this in `ionic serve`, I followed [this amazing tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/), that shows how to easily create a `proxy` in Ionic, and access other websites through that proxy.

It basically creates a path inside your `localhost`, like `http://localhost/api`, that points to the URL you want to access, so you won't get any CORS error, because you're accessing the same origin now!

It is very ease to configure. As the [tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) says, you just need to add the proxy configuration inside `ionic.config.json` file, like in the example:

```
{
    "name": "proxy-example",
    "app_id": "",
    "proxies": [
        {
            "path": "/api",
            "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
        }
    ]
}
```

And now you can make Ajax requests to `http://localhost:8100/api`!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, my preference would be to write the Android "SOAP Client" in Java.

But it's still possible to consume SOAP services from JavaScript.

Here is a good tutorial:

[SOAP Web Services in Angular and Ionic](http://mcgivery.com/soap-web-services-angular-ionic/)

This example uses "JavaScript SOAP Client": http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/